# Is This a Strictly Increasing Function?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

$$f(x)=x/(\sqrt{x^2+0.1})$$

if $x>y$ then f(x)>f(y), but the differences for big numbers are so small that could be negligible or we could say a.e. equal from a point on. So I'm just confused to consider those very small differences or not.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Negligible is not calculus. Negligible is numerical analysis (or asymptotic analysis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is strictly increasing, since its derivative is
$$f'(x)= \frac{0.1}{(x^2+0.1)^{3/2}} >0$$

Comment: This also shows why f is increasing very slowly.

Answer (score 1):

For $c>0$ (but as small as you want),

$$\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+c}}=\frac 1{\sqrt{1+\dfrac c{x^2}}}.$$

Obviously, when $x$ increases, the denominator decreases, from infinity down to $1$, so that the function increases from $0$ to $1$.

For different $c$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = x/\sqrt{x^2+c}$
where $c > 0$
then
$1/f(x) =\sqrt{x^2+c}/x
=\sqrt{1+c/x^2}$.

$c/x^2$ is decreasing for increasing $x$
so $1/f(x)$ is also decreasing
so $f(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: You are assuming that $x>0$.

Comment: I knew about it being increasing, Also being strictly, my problem was about that in limit point of view it goes to 1, and I thought it might be the case that we can say that it is almost everywhere 1, from a special point, but as @TheSilverDoe pointed out, its derivative is positive no matter what.